# Expected number of matches when two shuffled rows of $52$ playing cards are lined up

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

> Completely shuffle and then lay out a full deck of $52$ cards in a single row (i.e. single row $52$ columns). Do the same thing with a second deck of playing cards and place this deck in the second row(also has $52$ columns). What is the expected total number of matches in all the columns?

A *match* means that the top card and the bottom card in the column are the same (same rank and suit).

I was trying to solve it by brute force but seems like it's not that easy to me.

Comment: What is a match? Same rank and suit, or just same rank?

Comment: same rank and suit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $i=1$ to $52$, let $X_i=1$ if the cards in column $i$ match, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Then the number $Y$ of matches is given by $Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{52}$. It follows by the linearity of expectation that
$$E(Y)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots +E(X_{52}).$$
I expect you can find $E(X_i)$.

**Remark:** One could find the *distribution* of the number of matches. However, that is a much more complicated path to the expectation.  The method of *indicator random variables* can be very useful.

Comment: just one more question I'm feeling a little bit confused, are all **E(X_i)** s independent of each other?

Comment: The random variables are (fairly clearly) **not** independent. The linearity of expectation **does not** require independence, it holds unconditionally.

Comment: The distribution is that based on [rencontres numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers), though with a large number of cards such as $52$ then this will be close to the Poisson distribution with the expectation as calculated here.

Comment: I was wondering, isn't the probability for a card to match $\frac{1}{52}$? And as there are 52 events, shouldn't we expect only 1 card to match? @AndréNicolas

Comment: Yes, if by match you mean exact match, then $\Pr(X=1)=\frac{1}{52}$ and therefore $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{52}$ and therefore $E(Y)=1$. If you are satisfied with partial match (we care only about kind, not suit) same analysis works, but $\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{4}{52}$.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? This model assumes that it is possible to have 51 cards match. However, this isn't possible, because if one card does not match, it must have displaced  at least one other card.